# How to create three columns with equal margin in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to create three blocks displayed inline and centered:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

How to make equal margin for these `col-xs-6` blocks?

I mean this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div style="margin:10px" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
    <div style="margin:10px" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
    <div style="margin:10px" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
```

But that margin will be only between blocks inside

Comment: Equal margin to what? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Equal margin around three blocks `col-xs-6 col` inside `.row`

Comment: I confess I'm still not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Why not show us what this is *supposed* to look like as opposed to what you are getting.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: From what I understand, you want the 3 columns with an even gap between each (right margin), however you do not want the last column to have a right margin (because there is no point). I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the 3 columns with an even gap between each (right margin), however you do not want the last column to have a right margin (because there is no point).

You can make even margins between the columns, but have no margin on the last one, by using CSS `:not` selector, and check if element is not the `last-child` by using :

`not(:last-child)`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xghjqujc/3/)